# HTML and links via Quick press

Tags: html, links, dashboard

Is there any way I can add an HTML link from the quick press on the `/wp-admin` Dashboard? Does it accept HTML? If only I could do that, I wouldn't have to go to create new post every time I wanted to blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QuickPress does allow html to be added. Just try it. Add this as the content of your post inside QuickPress:

```
<b><a href="http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/">Test Link!</a></b>
```